# Write JSON to a log file and write each object on new line

Tags: python

I'm trying to write to a log file after pulling data using the API. After getting this, I'm iterating through so I can get the information that I want.

```
def write_audit_logs_file():
    audit_logs = get_audit_logs(get_zd_encoded_auth())

    with open('audit_logs_info.log', 'w') as out_file:

        for item in audit_logs['audit_logs']:
        
            out_file.write(json.dumps(item))      

write_audit_logs_file()
```

When I run this it writes to my file as a single line, but I want each JSON object to be on a separate line.

What I currently get is something like this:

```
{key:value, key:value, key:value}{key:value, key:value, key:value}{key:value, key:value, key:value}{key:value, key:value, key:value}
```

But what I want is this:

```
{key:value, key:value, key:value}
{key:value, key:value, key:value}
{key:value, key:value, key:value}
{key:value, key:value, key:value}
```

Comment: Can't you just add a newline character `\n` in each call to write?

Comment: It won't allow me to because it is not a str. I need this to stay as a object so that I can submit them as logs.

Comment: @jonrsharpe That prints multiples lines and that isn't want I'm looking for. I just want the objects themselves to be separate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can either append `'\n'`:

```
with open('audit_logs_info.log', 'w') as out_file:
    for item in audit_logs['audit_logs']:
        out_file.write(json.dumps(item) + '\n')
```

or alternatively use [`.join`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.join) (will probably be a bit faster if you have a lot of items in `audit_logs['audit_logs']` since it will only make a single `write` call):

```
with open('audit_logs_info.log', 'w') as out_file:
    out_file.write('\n'.join(json.dumps(item) for item in audit_logs['audit_logs']))
```

A shorter version with [`map`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#map), will still do a single `write` call:

```
with open('audit_logs_info.log', 'w') as out_file:
    out_file.write('\n'.join(map(json.dumps, audit_logs['audit_logs'])))
```

Comment: I did initially try appending '\n' and it wasn't working. Looking at this I can see what I did wrong. This was super helpful. Thank you!